# React Native how to restore a firebase session with tokenid

Tags: react-native, authentication, sessionid

How can I restore a sessionid in Firebase auth?

```
public async saveSessionId() {
    return auth().currentUser?.getIdToken().then((id) => {
        this.sessionId = id;
        AsyncStorage.setItem('@tokenid', this.sessionId);
    });
}

public async signInWithSessionId() {
    const credential = firebase.auth.???.credential(this.sessionId);
    return auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
}
```

Is there any provider or any method for reload session after reload the program?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one method will help you to reload the session.

```
public async signInWithSessionId() {
    const credential = firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(this.sessionId);
    return credential.user;
}
```

Comment: I received following error:
[auth/invalid-custom-token] The custom token format is incorrect.

I user @react-native-firebase/auth